# mac os zsh: command not found: pip

Tags: python, pip

I'm learning python and some article tell me that I should use `pip`, but when I trying to install pip success, it tells me

```
zsh: command not found: pip
```

this is my python

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
```

python version

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ python --version
Python 3.5.0
```

## User configuration

.zshrc

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/hedongfang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:/Users/hedongfang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@global/bin:/Users/hedongfang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/hedongfang/.rvm/bin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
```

I'm new in python, so if you want anything else,please tell me.

Comment: How did you install pip?

Comment: python get-pip.py

Answer (score 34):

If you are in MAC OS X you could try:
`sudo easy_install pip`

pip does not come native with MAC OS.

Comment: I try it just now but   sudo: easy: command not found

Comment: Sorry, I spelled it bad. Try with `easy_install`.

Comment: ➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo easy_install pip
Password:
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 31
    continue
           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation  I'm sorry I was busy with my job I

Comment: Got error: `Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')`

Comment: `sudo easy_install pip` is broken on newer macOs editions and running pip will crash.

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris you're right! try: `pip3` instead, it's supposed to already be installed, try: `pip3 -V`

Comment: Doesn't work on M1 chip

Comment: @samk for me, the best solution in Mac M1: first execute:
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` after: 
`python3 get-pip.py`